# Firestore security rules works don't work consistant across different environment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I have groupMembership who contain groupId, userId, status and the docId is combination between groupid + userId. I have groups object and events object who contain groupId. I want to allow access to events only to users which are inside the groups and have groupMembershup with status "active".

This is my firestore rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Firestore reusable functions
    function checkGroupStatus(groupId, userId) {
      let status = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groupMemberships/$(groupId+userId)).data.status;
      return status == "active";
    }

    // Allow reads for user's own profile - profile creation happens via cloud function
    match /profiles/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      // Make sure only authenticated users can read profiles
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    // Allow reads and delete to owners group membership
    match /groupMemberships/{documents=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

   // Allow reads to groups
    match /groups/{documents=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    // Allow reads to events
    match /events/{documents=**} {
      allow read: if checkGroupStatus(resource.data.groupId, request.auth.uid);
    }
  }
}
```

This is how i'm trying to get the events:

```
const eventsRef = collection(db, "events");
        const eventsQuery = query(
          eventsRef,
          where("groupId", "in", activeGroupIds),
          orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
          startAfter(lastDate),
          limit(10)
        );

 const eventsSnapshot = await getDocs(eventsQuery);
 const eventsData: P6Event[] = [];
 eventsSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   const eventData = doc.data();
   const eventId = doc.id;
   eventData.id = eventId;
   eventsData.push(eventData as P6Event);
 });
```

Everything works as expected at my local envinronment, but not working on prod.
I get this error: `@firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.3.0): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.` and `FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.`
Both local and prod has the same data in the firestore.

Comment: Are the rules deployed to prod?

Comment: Yes, I even play around with them tried to improve the functions like: `return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groupMemberships/$(groupId+userId)) && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groupMemberships/$(groupId+userId)).data.status == "active";`

Comment: Are you sure the user is authenticated on Prod app?

Comment: Yes, because I can get all the groups list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is caused by an unhandled `null` exception in your rules. When security rules result in an exception, they will automatically fail the request.

This line is where you mishandle the `null` value:

```
let status = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groupMemberships/$(groupId+userId)).data.status;
```

Your rules fail when the document at the given path does not exist because `get(path)` will return `null`. Attempting to call `(null).data.status` then throws an exception.

To fix this, you should instead grab the potentially `null` document object as your variable, and then handle it appropriately.

```
function checkGroupStatus(groupId, userId) {
  let groupMembershipDoc = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groupMemberships/$(groupId+userId));
  return groupMembershipDoc != null && groupMembershipDoc.data.status == "active";
}
```

**Note:** Your query also needs to pass the security rules checks for the request to succeed.

Comment: I tried still not working due to `Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: I think the problem is with `in` clause. Only the queries with the `in` clause are problematic.

Comment: @YordanMansarliyski Just to clarify `getDoc()` functions as intended, but the in query doesn't?

Comment: Yes, I had places in my code where I was using `==` clause and the rules work perfectly. But it's not working for the places where I'm using the `in` clause. Strange thing is locally everything works perfectly.

Comment: @YordanMansarliyski Have you checked that your [rules in the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/rules) match your local rules? Might be worth checking if they are out of sync

Comment: Yes, they match.